# Android - Multiple activities under a single tab, Fragments

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost, fragment

After scanning all the related questions regarding multiple activities under one tab, I found out that they all refer to using ActivityGroup which is **deprecated**.

Basically I have 2 tabs, the first one contains a main activity with several buttons and when button is clicked 1 for instance a new activity should open under the same tab, clicking back should bring me to the main view under the first tab. The second tab contains only one activity.

Tried inflating a new view for the sub-activities:

```
FrameLayout frameLayout = tabHost.getTabContentView();
frameLayout.removeAllViews();
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutID, tabHost, false);
frameLayout.addView(view);
```

But I only get the view, I cannot handle it like an activity; meaning adding buttons or listeners, it's only a view.

Google suggests using **fragments** instead, but I am having the hard time implementing this. Maybe replacing the activities with fragments could be the solution.

I could really use a good tab\fragments example right about now...

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes fragments are the way to go. In very broad terms, you should make your activities into fragments instead, and then make the tab activity show the fragments you desire.

Comment: Using fragments is basically the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the solution to your problem is using Android [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

I understand that you have trouble figuring out what to do. It's everybody's difficulty actually. However, with enough patience to google out things, you will realize it's actually not that difficult.

What I will be telling is basically some tips on how to change your code to fragments. From your current code, there's actually a major change you need to do but it's worth it.

What you are doing is actually you're making a dynamic UI. You have chunks of fragments which eventually can have different listeners which you should later on defined. Here's a sample [demo](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html) you can actually wok on.

If you want a detailed tutorial, I followed this [one](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html). And, yes, it works!

Have fun learning Android and don't forget Android is directly linked to Google. And you can easily google things and ask specific questions here should that question was never asked before.